# Operating on two Eithers

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, sanctuary, fantasyland

Suppose that you have the following code:

```
import R from "ramda";
import S from "sanctuary";
import { Left, Right } from "sanctuary-either";

const add = R.curry((p1, p2) => p1 + p2);
const addOne = add(1);

const func1 = () => Right(2);
const func2 = () => Right(7);
```

Combining `addOne` with `func1` or `func2` is relatively easy:

```
const res = R.compose(
  S.map(addOne),
  func1
)();
```

but how can one call `add` using `func1` and `func2` as arguments?

p.s. I know that ramda offers an `add` function. Consider the example as an abstraction of a real world problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`lift2` function](https://sanctuary.js.org/#lift2):

```
const addEithers = S.lift2(add)

console.log(addEithers(func1())(func2()))
```

Alternatively, you can use `ap`:

```
S.ap(S.map(add)(func1()))(func2())
```

Comment: Are you sure that this can be applied on an `Either`? I am getting a weird error "TypeError: ‘lift2’ applied to the wrong number of arguments". And the documentation states that it applies on `Apply`s. Same error for the `S.ap` as well

Comment: Yes, [`Either` implements `Apply`](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-either/tree/v2.1.0). I guess the currying is not optional in Sanctuary, and one needs to make two calls instead of passing two arguments? See the edit.

Comment: Ramda's [`lift`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lift) is similar; the currying is similarly mandatory.

Comment: @ScottSauyet The ramda docs you linked show a signature of `R.lift(add)(someEither, anotherEither)` not `R.lift(add)(someEither)(anotherEither)`, so it looks like `lift` is *not* completely curried but the partial application is optional?

Comment: @Bergi: sorry, you're right.  I should never go by memory even on a library I maintain!